# httpclient version conflict with cdh5.7

Tags: apache-spark, classpath, httpclient

I package **httpclient-4.5.1** into the application jar, than I use **spark-submit** to running the spark job, the following error occurred. 
The **spark** version is **1.6.0**.

```
17/04/10 15:26:19 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, cdh-5): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
```

and this is the **`pom.xml`**

```xml
    <!-- spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How to force to use the httpclient version in my jar ?

Comment: please, provide your `pom.xml` or `build` file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add httpclient library explicitly in your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It is already available in spark-core library.